# Notepad++ Remove Phrases Duplicated on a Line

Tags: notepad++, duplicates, phrase

I've some data that was sent to me and, for whatever reason, the sender managed to copy the data side by side three times, like so:

```
FileVersion 1   FileVersion 1   FileVersion 1   
FileRevision    0   FileRevision    0   FileRevision    0   
EDSVersion  4.0 EDSVersion  4.0 EDSVersion  4.0 
Description Gen4 (T,P,PS - DRL PMAC)26 April 2012 1 Description Gen4 (T,P,PS - DRL PMAC)26 April 2012 1 Description Gen4 (T,P,PS - DRL PMAC)26 April 2012 1 
CreationTime    02:02PM CreationTime    11:53AM CreationTime    06:28PM
CreationDate    02-27-2013  CreationDate    02-27-2013  CreationDate    02-26-2013
```

I need to delete every duplicate, and there's just over 22,000 lines in the data. Is there a way to delete duplicate phrases on a line in Notepad++?

Comment: You will need a script for that in some language. No IDE has that functionality to my knowledge.

Comment: How are the fields delimited? By a tab, by any chance? If so, you could use regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

Find what: `^(.+)\1\1`
Replace with: `$1`

This will work for almost all lines except for CreationTime & CreationDate because these lines have variable parts.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all the data was tab delimited, so I replaced all "\t" with ",", opened it in Excel as a CSV and deleted everything after the first two columns. Worked like a charm.